# how to run API and website on same IIS site

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor

i have

- serverside blazor project (website)
- web API made with entity framework core

both target 3.1. and as selfcontained projects.

my API routes are xxxxxx.com/api/*

i'm using unoeuro so dont have full control over the IIS as i understand it.

i can convert to applications, so i tried making a API folder and turn it into an application. But i guess there is something i need to change. Because when deploy the API it works, but then when i deploy the website the API stops working and gives me.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
Common causes of this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
```

So is there a file i need to specify this setup in.

Comment: "i'm using unoeuro so dont have full control over the IIS as i understand it"." - so ask them. Seriously, this is a standard setup in IIS but if you ahve no control maybe the project should be planned with what control you have - or you should actually work with a hoster where ou have control. Do you have any logs? "stops working" is like "lets start analyzing" except you seem to stop before doing analysis.

Comment: @TomTom you are correct, have added the error the API gives after deploying the website.

Comment: And which part of the error message do you have a problem understanding? Hint: you can deploy asp.net core with embedded runtime, then you bypass this error like always. IF the handler is installed on the server.... this looks like the server simply DOES NOT AHVE THE CORRECT RUNTIME. Pretty good explanation in the error, if you ask me.

Comment: @TomTom im adding both projects as selfcontained .

Comment: Ah, Either you do not, OR the server does not have the asp.net core hosting pack installed which adds the necessary IIS components (but no runtime). Goes back to "not programming but sytem administration" and "talk to your administrator".

Answer (score 0):

What i had to do was, run my api as a outofprocess application.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and change my AspNetCoreModuleV2 to AspNetCoreModule in web.config